# Linq .Where(type = typeof(xxx)) comparison is always false

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first

I'm trying to assign a `static List<PropertyInfo>` of all `DbSet` properties in the `Entities` class.

However when the code runs the List is empty because `.Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(DbSet))` **always returns false**.

I tried multiple variations in the `.Where(...)` method like `typeof(DbSet<>)`, `Equals(...)`, `.UnderlyingSystemType`, etc. but none works.

Why does `.Where(...)` always return false in my case?

My code:

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    //constructor is omitted

    public static List<PropertyInfo> info = typeof(Entities).getProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(DbSet)).ToList();

    public virtual DbSet<NotRelevant> NotRelevant { get; set; }
    //further DbSet<XXXX> properties are omitted....
}
```

Comment: `DbSet` != `DbSet<T>`... I'd say that's the problem

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Yes that was the problem. Are there resources online where I can read up the differences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `DbSet` is a separate type, you should use a more specific approach:

```
bool IsDbSet(Type t) {
    if (!t.IsGenericType) {
        return false;
    }
    return typeof(DbSet<>) == t.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
}
```

Now your `Where` clause will look like this:

```
.Where(x => IsDbSet(x.PropertyType))
```

Comment: Typo in code: `Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition` doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 You are right, thank you very much! You are welcome to edit code, especially when you see silly errors like this.